# How to start jobhost with TopShelf

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm using Topshelf to create a windows service and i'm thinking of integrate it with WebJobs SDK. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to setup? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you need to use TopShelf to create a windows Service. As WebJos is attached to the WebApp and [WebApp is SandBox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).It is not allowed us to install windows service on it.

If you want to use TopShelf, please have a try to use [Azure CloudService or Virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me) as a workaround.

Comment: My question is integrate with WebJobs SDK, not WebJobs.